# why Resonse.ok().build() return the Response entity itself?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, jax-rs

I have a simple REST API for which I am just returning Resonse.ok().build(), since the body of the function is asynchronous

I was expecting an empty response with a 200 http status code, but instead I got a full description of what seems to be the Response calls as entity.

What did I do wrong?

Here is the json response that I received from my API call

```
{
    "context": {
        "headers": {},
        "entity": null,
        "entityType": null,
        "entityAnnotations": [],
        "entityStream": {
            "committed": false,
            "closed": false
        },
        "length": -1,
        "language": null,
        "location": null,
        "committed": false,
        "mediaType": null,
        "allowedMethods": [],
        "links": [],
        "entityTag": null,
        "stringHeaders": {},
        "lastModified": null,
        "date": null,
        "acceptableMediaTypes": [
            {
                "type": "*",
                "subtype": "*",
                "parameters": {},
                "quality": 1000,
                "wildcardType": true,
                "wildcardSubtype": true
            }
        ],
        "acceptableLanguages": [
            "*"
        ],
        "entityClass": null,
        "responseCookies": {},
        "requestCookies": {},
        "lengthLong": -1
    },
    "status": 200,
    "length": -1,
    "language": null,
    "location": null,
    "metadata": {},
    "cookies": {},
    "mediaType": null,
    "allowedMethods": [],
    "links": [],
    "statusInfo": "OK",
    "entityTag": null,
    "stringHeaders": {},
    "entity": null,
    "lastModified": null,
    "date": null,
    "headers": {}
}
```

the REST api looks like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/accountworkers")
@Api(value = "/updater")
public class AccountUpdater {

    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccountUpdater.class);

    @Autowired
    private AccountUpdaterController auController;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/updater", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Response runUpdater() {
        LOGGER.info("Running account updater");
        auController.doAccountUpdateAsync();
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to mix JAX-RS and Spring MVC. These are not the same thing and are not compatible. By returning `Response`, which Spring MVC doesn't recognize, it it serializing it like it would any other entity. If you are using Spring MVC, then you want to be using [`ResponseEntity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html).

```
return ResponseEntity.ok().build()
```

If you are using Spring MVC, you should remove any dependencies for Jersey/JAX-RS so you don't get confused as to what you can and cannot use.

Aside, `@Produces` is also for JAX-RS. For Spring MVC, you are supposed to add the produces inside the [`@RequestMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) annotation.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
```

Comment: thank for the explanation, what is the proper way to do it in JAX-RS then? how do I know I mixed up JAX-RS and Spring MVC?

Comment: Look at packages of your imports. JAX-RS has `java.ws.rs` and Spring has `spring` in there. You can't just ask what is the proper way to do it in JAX-RS. You need to actually have your entire application set up and configured to run JAX-RS. Then you can go through any tutorial and see how the different annotations (i.e. `@Path`, `@Produces`, `@Consumes`, etc) are used. But right now, your application is running on the Spring MVC framework, so you need to follow the way their framework works.